# RStudio server increasing memory for allocation?

Tags: r, memory, server, rstudio, glm

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am running an incremental (forward and backward) glm where the data set contains 190 variables. I am trying to capture only the statistically significant variables using glm on RStudio Server and came to a halt when an error popped up stating "cannot allocate memory."  I was mentioned by a colleague to use `memory.limit()` to expand the memory in the R session but that is only available for windows. I have searched online and most people suggest using `R_MAX_MEM_SIZE`, but to my understanding that is only used when using the command prompt to run an R program.  Is there something else that anyone can recommend to use via RStudio script to control this or something similar to `memory.limit()` function?  I am running on 22 cores and the size of the main data file `DATOS` is 150MB.  Also, the server has 300GB of memory, which is plenty to do glm.  Over the 22 cores I am assuming that the main data file is passed to each node, but that should not take the whole memory of each node with the addition of the GLM computation.  I am aware there is a package called `Bigmemory` that deals with large data sets, but again I don't believe mine is that large.  Below is a simple example of my script and what I am trying to do as well as a screen shot of the error message.  I believe the main error occurs with glm having a large number of significant predictors / variables, that it goes beyond the limit of memory Rstudio defaults to.  If there is any other information that is needed, let me know so I can clear up any confusion.  Thank you in advance for any insight any one can provide.

```
 GLMFUNC <- function(nombres, DATOS, FORMULA, FAMILY, NA_ACTION =  na.exclude, pvalue = 0.05)
 {
library(foreach) # for loop to parallelize
library(doMC) # create the number of cores to use

# set the number of cores to use
registerDoMC(22)  # 22 number of CPU cores

form <- FORMULA
j = 1

repeat
{ 
pvalue_forloop <- foreach (i = 1:length(nombres), .combine = rbind) %dopar%
{
  if (j == 1) {
    form_temp <- paste(form, nombres[i], sep=" ")
  } else {
    form_temp <- paste(form, nombres[i], sep=" + ")
  }

  GLM <- glm(formula = as.formula(form_temp), na.action = NA_ACTION, # exclude NA values where they exist
             data = DATOS, family = FAMILY)

  temp <- as.numeric(as.character(coef(summary(GLM))[,4][length(GLM$coefficients)]))

  return(c(temp,nombres[i]))
}

 .... # does other stuff
 }
 }
```

Here is some info on the server that I am using

```
 Sys.info()
                          sysname                               release 
                          "Linux"          "2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64" 
                          version                              nodename 
 "#1 SMP Wed Apr 22 06:48:29 UTC 2015"               "cluster01.chapman.edu" 
                          machine                                 login 
                         "x86_64"                             "unknown"
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: RStudio Server Pro includes a `max-memory-mb` setting that you can use for this purpose. It's documented here:

http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/r-sessions.html#resource-limits

You may also find it helpful to read about memory limits in R:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html

However, both R and RStudio Server don't typically limit your usage, so it is likely that you're hitting an OS level limit (check ulimit).

Comment: Hi Johnathan, 

I did some digging and it seems I did hit OS level.  I had to decrease the number of cores that I was using and it all worked fine.